# How to process events which are out of order using Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have an application where events are sent on a Kafka topic based on user actions like User Login, user's Intermediate actions (optional) and User Logout. Each event has some information in a event object along with userId , for example a Login Event has loginTime; Add Note has notes (Intermediate actions). Similarly a Logout event has logoutTime. The requirement is to aggregate information from all these events into one object after receiving the Logout event for each user & send it on downstream.

Due to some reasons (Network delay, multiple event producer) events may not come in order (User Logout event may come before Intermediate event), So the question is how to handle such scenarios? I can not wait for Intermediate events after receiving User Logout event since Intermediate events are optional depending on user's actions.

The only option which I think here, is to wait for some time after receiving User Logout event, process Intermediate events if received within that wait time & send processed event, but again not sure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

`Kafka` does not guarantee order on `topic`, it guarantee order on `partition`. One topic can have more than one partition so every consumer that is consuming your topic will consume one partition. That is how kafka is achieving scalability. So what you are experiencing is normal behavior (it isn't bug or related to network delay or something like that). What you can do is to make sure that all messages that you want to proceed in order are sent to the same partition. You can do that by setting number of partitions to 1, that is the dumbest way. When you send message with producer, by default kafka take a look into key, take hash of it and by that hash know on which partition should send a message. You can make sure that for all messages, the key is the same. That way all hashes of keys will be the same and all messages will go to the same partition. Also, you can implement custom partitioner and override default way how kafka choose on which partition message will go. In this way, all messages will arrive in order. If you cannot do any of this actions, then you will receive events out of order and you will have to think about a way how to consume them out of order but that is not question related to kafka.

Comment: `but that is not question related to kafka` -- why not? It's absolutely related!

Answer (score 2):

If you are not able to preserve order of event (that Logout will be last event), 
you can achieve your requirements using [ProcesorApi](http://kafka.apache.org/23/documentation/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html) from Kafka Streams. Kafka Streams DSL can be combine with Processor API (more details [here](http://kafka.apache.org/23/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#id24)).

You can have several partitions, but all events for particular user has to be send to same Partition.

You have to implement custom Processor/Transformer. 
Your processor will be put each event/activity in state store (aggregate all event from particular user under same key). 
Processor API gives you ability to create some kind of *scheduler* ([Punctuator](https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html#id2)). 
You can schedule to check every ***X*** seconds events for particular user. If ***Logout*** was *long ago*, you get all events/activities and make some aggregation and send results to downstreams.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail, what you are trying to say?

Comment: @Swapnil, please first read attached links and then if you have any questions please ask

Comment: Makes me wonder if the Supress API https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-streams-take-on-watermarks-and-triggers should allow users to pass their custom logic (just like Windowed aggregation)

Answer (score 2):

As said in other answers, in Kafka order is maintained on per-partition basis.

Since you are talking about user events, why don't you make **UserID** as your Kafka topic key? So, that all events related to a specific user will always be ordered (provided they are produced by a single producer).

**You should ensure** (by *design*) that only one Kafka producer pushes all the user change events to the given topic. In this way, you can *avoid* out-of order messages due to multiple producers.

From streams, you might also want to look at Windows in Kafka streams. [Tumbling windows](https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#windowing-tumbling) for example is non-overlapping and fixed size. You aggregate records over a period of time.

Now you may want to sort the aggregated by their timestamp (or you said you have logout time, login time etc) and act accordingly.

---

**Simple and effective solution**

Use synchronous send and set `delivery.timeout.ms` and `retries` to a maximum value.
To ensure fault tolerance set `acks=all` with `min.insync.replicas=2` (topic configuration) and use a single  producer to push to that topic.
You should also set `max.block.ms` to some max value so that your `send()` does not return immediately if there is an error in fetching the metadata (for example, when Kafka is down).

> Benchmark the synchronous send with your rate and check to see if it meets your requirements or benchmark number.

This ensures that a message that came first is sent first to Kafka and then the next message is not sent until the previous message is successfully acknowledged.

> If your benchmark figure is not met, try having a back-pressure
>   mechanism like in-memory/persistent queue.

1. Add event to a queue in Thread-1
2. Peek (not dequeue) event from the queue in Thread-2
3. Call `producer.send(...).get()` in Thread-2
4. Dequeue the event in Thread-2

Answer (score 1):

The key is to make your frontend tracker to send ordered events to the backend service which then produces events to kafka.

You can achieve that by batching the events, and sending the batched events to the backend only after the previous batched events are successfully delivered.